# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre «también» y «tampoco»?

Tags: uso-de-palabras

Yo sé que se debe usar también cuando una persona se pone en acuerdo con una otra (en inglés, "You like movies? Me too!" será, "¿Te gustan las películas? ¡A mi también!") pero no se las reglas de usar para «tampoco». ¿Cuáles son? ¿Qué significa este diferencia?

Comment: Actually, your example of "¿Te gusta películas? ¡Yo también!" is incorrect... the response should be "¡A mi también!".  (This is one I learned the hard way.)

Comment: Se puede corregir mi pregunta; clique "edit" debajo de la etiqueta. :D No me importa si una otra persona mejora mi gramática.

Comment: One does not say, "una otra persona." Just "otra persona" will do; "otro" never takes a definite article.

Comment: @Brian Almost: "otro" doesn't take an *in*definite article.  It can take a definite article, however: "el otro", "las otras", etc.  You are right about "otra persona", though.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

"También" expresses accord with a positive meaning like English "too", "also", "as well".

> You like movies? I like movies **too**.
>
> ¿A ti te gustan las películas? A mí **también**.

"Tampoco" expresses accord with a negative meaning like English "not ... either" or "neither".

> You don't like movies? I don't like them **either**.
>
> ¿A ti no te gustan las películas? A mí no me gustan **tampoco**. (*or just* A mí **tampoco** me gustan.)

Comment: you should also say that if the **tampoco** stands before verb, there must not be double negation, so you avoid the **no**:  *"A mí **tampoco** me gustan."*

Comment: @TomasT.: Oh really? I didn't know that but it makes sense. Is my last example sentence wrong Spanish?

Comment: no, that's just another possibility, your example is correct.

Answer (score 2):

As explained in the textbook [*Vía Rápida (A1-B1), Difusión 2011*](http://www.difusion.com/ele/coleccion/metodos/adultos/via-rapida/general/):

**también**:

- to add an item of the same type in a new phrase:
  *Estudio portugués y francés. También estudio alemán.*
- to express coincidence of opinions or information in positive (non-negative) phrases:
  *A Marta le gusta bailar. Y a Ana también.*

**tampoco**:

- to add an item of the same type in a negative phrase:
  *No me gusta la música electrónica. Tampoco me gusta la música clásica.*
- to express coincidence of opinions or information in negative phrases:
  *Sergio no habla inglés y Diana tampoco.*

Comment: Would the first *tampoco* example translate as, "I don't like electronic music. Nor do I like classical music." ?

Comment: @AarthiDevanathan Exactly. "Tampoco" is even mentioned in the dictionary entry for "nor": http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=nor, and viceversa. An example from the dictionary: _No he visto esa película. - Yo tampoco._ ("I haven't seen that film." "Neither (o nor) have I.")

Answer (score 0):

As a simple summary, both express agreement.

También expresses agreement with a positive sentence.
Tampoco expresses agreement with a negative sentence.

Yo corro mucho.  Yo también.  (I run a lot.  Me too.)
Yo nunca corro.  Yo tampoco.  (I never run.  Me neither.)